# If specific columns match, add them to the same row using BASH

Tags: awk

I have data that looks like this:

```
client1 5 10 12 17
client1 6 8 3 20
client1 3 2 2 2
client2 3 3 3 3 
client2 4 4 0 0
client2 0 3 3 9
...
client100 3 3 2 1
client100 1 1 1 2
client100 3 3 4 4
```

I want to make it so there is only one row for every client, with all the information of each client row, merged into one.  So for example, client1 and client2 would look like this merged (but obviously I need all the clients merged.)

```
client1 5 10 12 17 6 8 3 20 3 2 2 2
client2 3 3 3 3 4 4 0 0 0 3 3 9
```

```
awk '{ x[$1]=x[$1] " " $2; y[$2]=y[$2] " " $1; } 
END { 
   for (k in x) print k,x[k] >"OUTPUT1";  
   for (k in y) print k,y[k] >"OUTPUT2"; 
}' INPUT
```

Comment: What is `OUTPUT2` for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're merging, you need to add all the fields, not just field 2. The easiest way to do this is to empty field 1, then append the whole record to the array entry.

```
awk '{ client = $1; $1 = ""; x[client] = x[client] $0 }
     END { for (k in x) print k x[k] }' INPUT
```

I'm not sure what your array `y` was for. There doesn't seem to be any reason for an array that uses the second field as the keys.

Comment: Isn't it just `x[client] = x[client] $0` and `print k x[k]` ?

Comment: @jhnc If you do that you won't get a space between them.

Comment: I don't think `k=$1;$1=""` strips the space before `$2`: `echo 1+2+3 | awk -F+ -v OFS=+ '{$2="";print $0}'` -> `1++3`

Comment: Hey Barmar, this works great!  Problem I have (and I probably should have added this.)  I have about 15 rows per client.  After I merge them, and take that file into Excel, all 15 don't end up in a nice row.  Some of the rows end up on different lines.

Comment: I can't see any reason for that in the awk code. Are they on different lines in the output file?

Comment: I just tested my code, and it always keeps all the columns for the same client in a single line in the output file. Sounds like the problem may be with how you're importing it into excel.

Comment: Yes, so in the output file, the second row will be missing the clients name (as if had been merged.)  I will say, my "sample test" is not as long as the real dataset.  In the real dataset, there are 12 numbers per client (some with decimals) so it can get long.  Do you think that could be the issue?

Comment: Check your input file for carriage return characters. Use `dos2unix` to remove them.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following. This should provide output in same order in which `$1` has occurred in Input_file.

```
awk '
{
  gsub(/\r/,"")
}
!a[$1]++{
  b[++count]=$1
}
{
  val=$1
  $1=""
  sub(/^ +/,"")
  c[val]=(c[val]?c[val] OFS:"")$0
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
    print b[i],c[b[i]]
  }
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk '                                    ##Starting awk program.
{
  gsub(/\r/,"")
}
!a[$1]++{                                ##Checking condition if $1 is NOT in array a then do following.
  b[++count]=$1                          ##Creating array b with index count and value is $1.
}
{
  val=$1                                 ##Creating a variable val whose value is $1.
  $1=""                                  ##Nullifying $1 here.
  sub(/^ +/,"")                          ##Substituting initial space with null here.
  c[val]=(c[val]?c[val] OFS:"")$0        ##Creating an array c whose index is variable val and value is complete line value and its concatenating its own value each time cursor comes here.
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){                 ##Starting a for loop from i=1 till value of count here.
    print b[i],c[b[i]]                   ##Printing value of array b with index i and array c with index of b[i].
  }
}
' Input_file                             ##Mentioning Input_fie name here.
```

Comment: @Barmar, Code format is done, explanation is on the way sir :)

Comment: @Barmar,Hi sir, I have added detailed  explanation for code now, please do lemme know in case I need to improve anything here.

Comment: Nice. Why do you need the `a` and `b` arrays instead of just `for (k in c)`? Is it just to keep the clients in the original order?

Comment: It's not clear that preserving order is a requirement. If it is, then you do indeed need this complex method instead of my simpler script.

Comment: @Barmar, just for safer side in case people want in same order I had posted it. Array a makes sure about elements occurance part and b makes sure it's sequence part.